# Setting up working environment - Konsole or other terminal - open few tabs and run some commands

Tags: scripting, console, desktop-environment, konsole, api

I have a working environment where I run a web server, TSC compiler, and then work in few directories in a console, and also run few programs - IDE, 2x gitk, krusader.

I would like to be able to launch all that with one command. This would open some terminal app, probably Konsole, create few tabs in it, run some commands in those terminals (which would launch the server, and the other apps).

I know how I would do this on Windows - even if the app has no API, you can send WinAPI messages to the app and emulate events.

How can I do this hooking in on Linux?
Does Konsole have some scriptable API?
Or does some terminal emulator support this as a feature?

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779281/how-to-launch-a-kde-konsole-with-multiple-tabs-running-various-progs .

Comment: That helps, I can do the core of what I want. Thanks.